# Combining dynamic service with map cache using ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, cache

What I would like is a single ArcGIS Service that caches at the largest levels (state, regional, city) but is then just dynamic at sub city levels. From what I'm reading and understanding -- I think this is not possible -- one would have to have two separate services that display at different levels.

And yes, I know you can do the "create tiles on demand", but space, speed issues and the fact that I can't even get it to work at the moment is not ideal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in a single service, but you could do it with two services using scale ranges for visibility.  Cache the one and leave the other dynamic.

As far as creating tiles on demand:
Space, I understand.  If you don't have it you don't have it.
Speed "issues" only occur for the first person ever to request the area.  Thereafter, it goes as fast as the tiled maps and doesn't take hardly any CPU.
I would look into why you can't get it to work.  It could be permissions.  What version of ArcGIS Server do you have?